# Default network gateway value for docker-compose version 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gateway, docker-network

I'm creating a `Nginx` container using `docker-compose` under version `3.7`

I'm trying to specify the `ipam` attribute. But when I read from the below official reference:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference

There is a note and I understand that the `gateway` can be only specified under version `2`.

> Note: Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment.

So I tried without specifying the `gateway` under `ipam` attribute. My container still can be created and running.

Then I go and check on the `docker-network` setting. After I inspected and observed there is no specified `gateway`. But my `Nginx's access.log` still shows the traffic from the `172.19.100.1` which I assumed that it's the `gateway`.

```
"IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.100.0/24"
                }
            ]
        }
```

What I want to know and be clarified that under version `3.7`, are there any methods that I can specify the `gateway` inside `docker-compose` file or what is the default value if I cannot specify?

Also, should it be recommended to write `docker-compose` under version `2` instead of `3`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

- create a network and give it a name (awesomenet for example).
- configure the network in your docker-compose.yml as "external" (this way compose will not try to create and use a new network).
- configure your services to use the external network you created earlier.

On your shell (chose the IP range to suit your needs):

```bash
docker network create --gateway "172.172.0.1" --subnet "172.172.0.0/16" awesomenet
```

docker-compose.yml (or docker-compose.override.yml in your dev env):

```yaml
version: "2.4"
services:
  webserver:
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    ...
    networks:
      - awesomenet
  another_service:
    ...
    networks:
      - awesomenet
networks:
   awesomenet:
     external: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input ^^ Actually, my question is for `docker-compose` version 3 instead :D

Comment: Are you refering to the first statement `version: "2.4"` ? Because if you are, I did a quick test using `version: "3"` and everything is still working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2024, the Docker Compose V3 spec still has a statement saying `Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment.`

In the docker compose file you can still set the gateway like this

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  default:
    name: my-network
    ipam: 
      config:
        - subnet: 172.33.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.33.0.1
```

If you describe this network using `docker network inspect my-network` you can see that even for V3 the gateway config is stored

```
...
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.33.0.0/16",
            "Gateway": "172.33.0.1"
        }
    ]
},
...
```

however it appears that the gateway setting is not actually used i.e. it is not honored, as per the note in Docker Compose V3 spec.

I have determined this by attempting to access the host via the gateway address on the bridged network and it doesn't resolve. However, when not specifying the gateway or subnet properties Docker Compose assigns a gateway value and you *can* use that to access the host machine on a bridged network. In other words, if you let Docker Compose handle the subnet and gateway then it works, but if you attempt to specify this it does not work as expected in my observations.

More information here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipam